# Trying to install ubuntu for nexus unable to locate package

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-10

I am trying to install on my nexus 10 Ubuntu. But every time I try to install

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb
android-tools-fastboot Reading package lists... Done Building
dependency tree        Reading state information... Done E: Unable to
locate package phablet-tools E: Unable to locate package
android-tools-adb E: Unable to locate package android-tools-fastboot
```

this appears. Could you please help me

Thanks

Comment: The **phablet-tools** package is now deprecated. You should be using: **`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash`**. *This also requires the **Universe** repository to be enabled.*

Answer (score 3):

I guess you haven't added the PPA which has the tools you're looking for. From [Ubuntu wiki's instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Step_1_-_Desktop_Setup)

> **Setup the Touch Developer Preview Tools PPA**
>
> The PPA has the tools and dependencies to support Precise, Quantal, and Raring. Add the Ubuntu Touch PPA by adding the following custom source list entry to your /etc/apt/sources.list file.
>
> On your computer, press Ctrl+Alt+T to start a terminal.
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
>
> or if add-apt-repository is not available, append the following to your sources.list:
>
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu [dist-codename] main
>
> deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu [dist-codename] main
>
> *Note: replace [dist-codename] with precise, quantal, raring or saucy.
>
> Then do the following:
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ubuntu you use?

On your computer, open a terminal:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on ubuntu 13.04 with nexus 4, I failed to install `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash` so I tried to root the device using [Ubuntu Nexus 7 Desktop Installer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) and I followed the instruction here [DualBootInstallation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation). i worked ;)

[image]